# Select info from a record that has max date and specific foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, yii, criteria

I have two tables named `barang` and `request`, I want to display in my gridview, the value of `peminjam` column in `barang` table where `id_barang` (PK in `request` table) equals to `id_barang` (FK in `barang` table), and where the record has the latest date (`tanggal_request` column in `request` table).

I did this in `Barang.php` model:

```
$id_barang = $this->id_barang;
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = 'max(tanggal_request)';
$criteria->addColumnCondition(array('id_barang' => $id_barang));
$model = Request::model();
$value = $model->commandBuilder->createFindCommand(
     $model->tableName(), $criteria)->queryScalar();
$hasil = $value;
return $hasil;
```

It showed me the max date indeed. I don't know how to display the `peminjam`.
I tried this:

```
$criteria->select = '*';
...
$hasil = $value->peminjam;
```

But it said this:

> Trying to get property of non-object.

I also tried this:

```
$criteria->select = '*';
...
$hasil = $value['peminjam'];
```

But it said this:

> Illegal string offset 'peminjam'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:

```
$id_barang = $this->id_barang;
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select = 'peminjam';
    $criteria->limit = "1";
    $criteria->with = array(
    'request' => array(
    'together'=>true,
    'order'=>"tanggal_request DESC",
    'condition'=>"request.id = $id_barang"
    )
    );
    $data = Barang::model()->find($criteria);
    echo $data->peminjam;
```

Your code seems fine the only problem is that you're trying to fetch `peminjam` column from `barang` table and I don't see that model being used for the query, maybe that is why you're not getting any value for `peminjam`.

Comment: You should include some explanation of what is wrong with the OP's code and what your code does to fix it

Comment: @Safira You're trying to fetch `peminjam` column from `barang`, I don't see thst model being used for the query, maybe that is why you're not getting any value for `peminjam`